# Custom Post Type Categories Not Maintaining URL structure any more

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, taxonomy, urls

I'm having a really hard time with this... I have a custom post type called "locations" that has several taxonomies for it.  I was originally able to get it so that when you clicked on the category / taxonomy, the url and content pulled up just fine without any issues.

However, I updated to wordpress 4.0 friday and since (might be indirectly responsible, or an updated plugin), it seems that the urls are weird and not pulling the custom post type category.

The "locations" main page with ALL of custom post types comes up fine, and when you click on an individual custom post type, those come in too.  However, still when you just try to click on "retail" for example as the category which should pull in the post types for all of "retail" posts that category, it's not doing it and the page is just completely blank... I have PHP error reporting on, but nothing is showing up.

So, to make it more clear what's happening, this link doesn't come up blank without anything  at all for the category of my custom post type:

http://mydevsite.com/?locations_cats=retail

HOWEVER, if you just manually type "locations" as the parent custom post type before the ?, it comes up just fine with all of the posts in that category...
http://xmgpreview.com/playtime/locations/?locations_cats=retail

So, I'm not sure what's going on...  below is the code I am using for it.  Can someone PLEASE help?  Not sure why this isn't working any more, and the client wants to go live with the site soon. :?

I'll try to provide the code used for my taxonomy if that helps...

Comment: Start off by resetting your permalinks by visiting the Settings > Permalinks page. Does that fix it? If not, are the taxonomies still appearing in the dashboard (presumably as child menu items in the Locations submenu?)

Comment: Hmm not sure why as I cleared the permalinks before, but that somehow seemed to fix it, as well as disabling, and enabling a few plugins agaiin. PHEW!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from your post that somehow the rewrite rules in your .htaccess file were lost/reset/corrupted.

As long as your `register_post_type()` code remains unchanges, you can visit "Settings > Permalinks" to reset them and fix your issue.